# Cannot see tablet screen while it ts connected to the TV

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, screen, hdmi

I have a Serioux s101 tablet and when I'm connecting it to my TV(Toshiba P1300D) it works fine but my tablet's screen becomes blank. Is there a way to see both screens?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using a USB cable or some sort of wireless connection, or an HDMI cable. If you're using HDMI you should still be able to see your tablets screen. Also, check the input/output settings for your TV.